# Is it possible to center the React Bootsrap ProgressBar's label?

Tags: css, reactjs, progress-bar, react-bootstrap

I'm working with React-Bootsrap ProgressBar and I notice the component aligns its label based on its value:
[progress-bar example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAoyF.png)

I was wondering if it was possible to center the label regardless its value, like this: [(random example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FeQQ.png)

My component:

```
<ProgressBar
    now={....}
    label={....}
    className={....}
/>
```

Result on browser dev tools:

```
<div class="..... progress">
    <div role="progressbar" class="progress-bar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-    valuemax="100">
        dummy
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried styling the progress and progress-bar classes, but I couldn't style the text inside

Comment: Did you try using CSS classes? for example, className="text" in JSX tag and .text{color: red} in the styles.

Comment: Yep, I tried to do the same thing that saidtechnology suggested on his answer

Comment: If you use "react-bootstrap" you might have to try "!important" right after the CSS property. For example .text{color: red !important}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, I created an issue on react-boostrap GitHub about this subject: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/6741

Basically, there is no "official" method to achieve this (eg: by setting a parameter or stylying it). So the workaround is to put the label on a div inside the ProgressBar component.

Eg:

```
<ProgressBar className="position-relative">
  <div className="position-absolute d-flex justify-content-center w-100 text-danger">25%</div>
  <ProgressBar striped variant="success" now={25} key={1} />
</ProgressBar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible, try this.

```html
<ProgressBar 
now={60} 
label={`${60}%`}
className="progress-bar-wrapper"
/>
```

And in CSS

```css
.progress-bar-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.progress-bar-wrapper::after {
  content: attr(data-label);
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work for me :( 
I applied the css styles but it's still like the first image...
I'm on: "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2"

Comment: After studying and testing this code, I noticed why wasn't working for me.
The React-Bootstrap's ProgressBar renders:
<div class="......progress-bar-wrapper progress">
<div class="progress-bar">dummy</div>
</div>

That's why it don't work on my case, because the first div (where the style goes), does not have any data-label attribute (nor any other attribute, besides 'class'). The label attribute does exists on the component, but it's not redered, so the attr() function on CSS returns nothing